# SYSTEM_ERROR: system encountered unexpected error. Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I create project on firebase Blaze Plan and I load testing with J Meter with 300 Invocations/Second and I got error from Logs in Cloud Function. What does this error mean?

Very confused. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I saw the same thing and also did increase the ram size but still got this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Common function termination reasons are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting). Note that Firebase Functions is just a wrapper around [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions).

**Out of memory**

Check for the out of memory logging error line. It should say `Function invocation was interrupted. Error: memory limit exceeded.` If you're on Node.js v12+, note there are [some extra flags](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting) that can be set to use large amounts of memory.

**Timeouts**

Timeouts are another common failure cause, indicated by the log entry `Function execution took <XXX> ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

**Find the failing invocation logs**

Overall, to debug this sort of thing, I'd suggest looking at the logs for the specific function invocation that caused this error. Usually you can do this by adding the `labels.execution_id="<my-id>"` to the logging query. You can find that value in the fully expanded error log line in the Cloud Logging viewer.

**Internal GCF Failure**

Sometimes things just don't work out: `Function invocation was interrupted. SYSTEM_ERROR: system encountered unexpected error.` This happens, rarely. I run millions of invocations a day and see about 3 of these a day. Try adding a [retry](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) to your function to handle these cases, if the logic is idempotent.

Finally, if that doesn't work, try escalating to support. Best luck.